# issue in showing loading panel on button submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

**HTML**

```
<div style="display: none; vertical-align: middle;" id="imgdiv">
<img src="../Images/circular.gif" alt="" /></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $("#imgdiv").css('display', 'block'); 
 $("#imgdiv").fadeIn(500); 
 setTimeout(function () {
    $("#imgdiv").fadeIn(4000); 
  }, 3000);
 return true;
```

The icon is not spinning in IE and the background is not faded. The background is displaying completely hidden with gray color.And the spinning image is Static. But working in all the other browsers. Any idea?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? is it working fine in other browsers? your question is a little different from your description

Comment: IE 10. Yes, it is working in all the other browsers except IE.

Comment: What background? I don't see any background here

Comment: can you try setting up an example on jsfiddle.net? It's hard to figure out what the problem might be

Answer (score 1):

try this, working on ie8

```
<div style="display: none; vertical-align: middle;" id="imgdiv">
<img src="../Images/circular.gif" alt="" /></div>
<script>

 //$("#imgdiv").css('display', 'block'); 
 $("#imgdiv").fadeIn(500); 
 setTimeout(function () {
    $("#imgdiv").fadeIn(4000); 
    return true;
  }, 3000);

</script>
```

The error on the IE debugger was: **return istruction is out of the function**

I also don't understand why you coded 2 fadein after a display block, if the display is block, fadein won't start..

**EDIT: check this two differents examples**

```
<div style="width:400px;height:400px;display: none; vertical-align: middle;background:url('http://eatingatoz.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/B.png') no-repeat" id="imgdiv2">
<img style="display:none;" id="img2" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2919748222/193af07952fca7f5247da6cc1fe84a6d.jpeg" alt="" /></div>


<script>
 $("#imgdiv2").css('display', 'block'); 
 $("#img2").delay(2000).fadeIn(function(){$('#img2').fadeOut(3000)});
</script>

<div style="width:400px;height:400px;display: none; vertical-align: middle;background:url('http://eatingatoz.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/B.png') no-repeat" id="imgdiv">
<img id="img" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2919748222/193af07952fca7f5247da6cc1fe84a6d.jpeg" alt="" /></div>


<script>
 //$("#imgdiv").css('display', 'block'); 
 $("#imgdiv").fadeIn(function(){$('#img').fadeOut(3000)}).delay(2000);
</script>
```

Comment: @User I don't see any background set for imgdiv and, anyway, after the first fadeIn of imgdiv, nothing will happens. check the code I added, maybe I understood your needs.